In a Netsuite Saved Search, how do I display all User Notes AND where they come from?
Alright, so if I go to Reports > New Search and run a User Note search, I am able to see all of the notes I would expect to see; however, I am not able to distinguish between them in the way I would like. Right now, I have a few notes made directly on some customer records (under Communications > User Note for a Customer), but I also have notes made directly on invoices, which are a different record type (transaction vs customer/entity). When I run the barebones User Note search, I see all these notes together, and if someone chose a type like phone call, or email, I can see that "type", but I can't seem to figure out a way to display both the transactions notes and the customer notes and add a higher-level type field that will identify them as being user notes from a transaction/invoice record vs an entity/customer record.
For example, I tried adding a Formula (Text) field to the Results tab that would look at transactions.type, like so:
CASE WHEN {transaction.type} = 'Invoice' then 1 ELSE 0 END
I tried several permutations of this approach but nothing seems to work. I basically just need some sort of high level record type field, and that doesn't seem to exist. Does this need to be done in two reports?
I've tried adding native fields, creating formula fields, etc., and everything I've attempted has either 1) eliminated the user notes search results that are from customer records, leaving me with just the transaction user notes, or 2) simply errored the formula field and my results remained unchanged.

If you are using the advanced search you can add a column for each potential record type.
e.g. on the Results tab add a new field. Scroll to the bottom until you can see Transaction Fields.... Click that and then choose Document Number.
When you run the search anything with a transaction number was attached to a transaction.
With that in mind you can create a Formula Text column with a title like 'Created From' like:
case when {transaction.tranid} is not null then 'Transaction' 
case when {customer.entityid} is not null then 'Customer'
case when {task.internalid} is not null then 'Task'
...
else 'unknown' end

